# R 3.1.1 on Windows - Connecting from Outside of Amazon EC2—Firewall Timeout Issue

Tags: r, amazon-redshift, rpostgresql

I'm currently playing around with accessing AWS Redshift through R via the RPostgreSQL package. Everything works fine until I try to submit more complex queries which take longer to run. When submitting these queries the connection times out as described at the bottom of the following Amazon AWS post  (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-firewall-guidance.html). 
However although I'm able to change these settings in SQL workbench/J, I'm not sure how I can change these settings in R?

Comment: I would say it is a Windows issue, which has nothing to do with R.

Comment: Hi Pascal, thank you very much for the reply. That could well be the case however I would currently doubt this. As after changing the values in the windows registry and updating the connection string to contain jdbc:postgresql://examplecluster.abc123xyz789.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/**dev?tcpKeepAlive=true** as per the amazon document I manage to resolve the problem in another program (SQL workbench/J).

Comment: If modifying the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\` (and a reboot) didn't help the `RPostgreSQL` package/driver keep your connection active, then you'll have to switch to one of the ODBC packages for R and connect to Redshift that way (since you can explicitly pass the `?tcpKeepAlive=true` as part of the ODBC query string parameters.